# Skinning AIR application window

Tags: apache-flex, air

I'm using mx:WindowedApplication, I'm wondering how I can skin the title bar and close/minimize button for the window. I can see application like Pandora One is using it and setting transparency. Any pointer to a doc?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your application.xml file, uncomment and set:

```
<systemChrome>none</systemChrome>
```

and

```
<transparent>true</transparent>
```

Then draw whatever you want for window controls. You'll have to implement your own dragging IIRC, as well as making the appropriate AIR API calls for minimize and maximize.